# Align tool not working on Illustrator CC 2014

Tags: adobe-illustrator, alignment, mac

It's kinda weird. I'm unable to figure out why 'Align' tool is not working on my Illustrator.

If it's of help; i'm on Yosemite with CC 2014 latest release.

PS: I'm using Mac for past 2 days only, so not much sure about things. Possibly i'm doing something wrong. Would really appreciate some quick help.

Thanks

[image: Please check image]

Comment: I can't really grasp much from this image, it looks like you only have one item selected? Try drawing two items and then hitting an align option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is *exceptionally* unclear. You have a single object selected, you do not offer *any* information as to how you are trying to align that single object nor any detail as to what exactly isn't working. However....

Align has three functions:

1. Align to arbaord
2. Align to other objects (selection)
3. Align to a single key object

[image]

[image]

Items 2 and 3 **require** more than one object be selected before they function.

The **only** time you can use the align functions on a single object is when **Align to artboard** is selected as the alignment method.

Based on your screen shot, with only one object selected, I would guess that you do not have the options set to Align to Artboard.

Comment: Thanks. This was really helpful.
I'm sorry for the unclear question. I should have written it properly.